# How to display limited records instead of all records using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my iframe i have many records, but my requirement is to show only 4 records not all.
I will provide a "Show All" link, once click on show all link we have to display all records in the another tab.

Comment: Use `.hide()` and `.show()` to hide and show some records.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592), and we also [don't answer homework questions](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166) (ignore if you're not asking about hw). Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a [mcve]. For further information, please see [ask], and take the [tour] :)

Comment: A good practice will be if you try to do it. Don't get me wrong, we love helping people. But it is really important to test your curiosity and finding a way of solving problems. And when ever you are stock, your questions will surely be answered. See the [How to, Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: did you try with table?

Answer (score 0):

I have added here a sample code with table, hope it will help you out.

### html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Alice</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Bob</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Carol</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <button class="show-all">Show all</button>
  <button class="show-default">Show default</button>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $("table > tbody > tr").hide().slice(0, 2).show();
    $(".show-all").on("click", function() {
      $("tbody > tr", $(this).prev()).show();
    });
    $(".show-default").on("click", function() {
      $("table > tbody > tr").hide().slice(0, 2).show();
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```